# Neophite struggling to set up Ubuntu in a USB stick

Tags: live-usb

I have installed ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64 using Rufus 2.17 on  a USB. My laptop is an HP Pavilion with Intel Core i5 7th generation configured to allow USB boot. I followed the instruction on the Ubuntu site but it did not work.
Can anyone suggest what can I do to address this issue?

Comment: What errors are we seeing?

Comment: The laptop boots in Windows. I have already double checked and the BIOS is set to allow USB boot. I stick the USB in and switch the laptop on and nothing, I get Windows.